# Request header field X-Parse-Master-Key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: parse-platform

I'm currently configuring my web application to use the Parse.com Schema API to fetch schema information, following the official documentation:

https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas-fetch-the-schema

This documentation specifies that you must add the `X-Parse-Master-Key` as a header on the request. However, when that header is added, the request is rejected with the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.parse.com/1/schemas. Request
>   header field X-Parse-Master-Key is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

After looking at the response, it appears that the Parse.com Schema API endpoint does not include `X-Parse-Master-Key` within `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`:

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Parse-REST-API-Key,
>   X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token,
>   X-Requested-With, Content-Type

Has anyone else experienced this issue with the Schema API, or is there something that I've missed? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @Ankita - unfortunately not.